# Ambiguous method overloading for method grails.spring.BeanBuilder#registerBeans

Tags: grails

I'm following Mike Kelly's brilliant tutorial videos but I have been stumped by the following problem. It happens when I add a new Domain Class. I've tried backing out changes and adding a DomainClass with a different name, restarting the IDE, etc. With only one Domain Class I have no error, if I add one the error appears.

I'm working with ggts 3.4.0, Grail 2.3.1, JDK 1.7.0_45.

```
 | Error 2013-11-04 21:56:37,442 [Thread-8] ERROR plugins.AbstractGrailsPluginManager  - Plugin [domainClass:2.3.1] could not reload changes to file [C:\Grails\ProjectTracker\grails-app\domain\projecttracker\EndUser.groovy]: Ambiguous method overloading for method grails.spring.BeanBuilder#registerBeans.
Cannot resolve which method to invoke for [null] due to overlapping prototypes between:
    [interface org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.RuntimeSpringConfiguration]
    [interface org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionRegistry]
Message: Ambiguous method overloading for method grails.spring.BeanBuilder#registerBeans.
Cannot resolve which method to invoke for [null] due to overlapping prototypes between:
    [interface org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.RuntimeSpringConfiguration]
    [interface org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionRegistry]
    Line | Method
->> 2980 | chooseMostSpecificParams     in groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug. I was able to reproduce the problem when I was investigating http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-10735 .

Answer (score 0):

You can override the ambiguous method when passing null to its parameter

```
MyClass.metaClass.myAmbiguousMethod = {def param ->
    if(param != null){
        myAmbiguousMethod(param)
    } else{
        null
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I can reproduce this in grails 3.2.4 by providing a `render invalidVariable`statement. Bad argument to `render` can cause this from what I can tell

Comment: Can you explain your answer?  This looks like just a comment on the question not an answer.